# React w/ JSX: Load class defined in JSX into HTML

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to React and have attempted going through a few tutorials but do not have luck so I resort to asking question here.

My setup: I have a .jsx file that contains a class definition:

**HelloWorld.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='greeting-div'>
                <div>
                    HELLO WORLD JSX
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to do this in my index.html (app.js contains the main JS assets):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/app.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/HelloWorld.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greeting-div"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <HelloWorld/>,
        document.getElementById('greeting-div')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I configured my webpack.config.js this way

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var paths = require("./paths.js");
var files = require('./files.js');
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        HelloWorld : path.join(paths.hello, "HelloWorld"),
        app: ["react", "react-dom", "react-bootstrap", "jquery", "underscore"]
    },

    output: {
        path: paths.webappAssets,
        publicPath: "",
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[chunkhash].js",
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: '[name]'
    },
};
```

As you may have expected, this setup does not work and I am stuck. I suspect it has something to do with how I am calling ReactDOM (maybe it belongs in the jsx?)

Anyway, some guidance would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope that helps. DO something like that.

HelloWorld.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='greeting-div'>
                <div>
                    HELLO WORLD JSX
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorld/>,
  document.getElementById('greeting-div')
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greeting-div"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_OF_YOUR_OUTPUR_SCRIPT" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js :

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var paths = require("./paths.js");
var files = require('./files.js');
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'PATH_OF_YOUR_HelloWorld.jsx'),
    },

    output: {
        path: paths.webappAssets,
        publicPath: "",
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[chunkhash].js",
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: '[name]'
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed your setup and encountered this console error: HelloWorld.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp_name_ is not defined

Comment: OK. I got this to work with 2 additional changes. (1) vendor.js (or app.js) needs to be referenced way before (e.g. in <head>). (2) The reference to the compile HelloWorld.js needs to be in <body>. I put it at the end of <body> at suggested here and it worked. Thanks for your help dude.